# Redirect user after registration via separate registration page to a specific page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to redirect users when they click the register button to the my-account billing page. I had this working perfectly using via the code from [Redirect after registration to WooCommerce "my account" edit address page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69825843/11987538) answer code.

However that was when the register and login pages were on the same page, now however I've had to make a different registration page using the code:

```php
add_shortcode( 'wc_reg_form_bbloomer', 'bbloomer_separate_registration_form' );
    
function bbloomer_separate_registration_form() {
   if ( is_admin() ) return;
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return;
   ob_start();
 
   // NOTE: THE FOLLOWING <FORM></FORM> IS COPIED FROM woocommerce\templates\myaccount\form-login.php
   // IF WOOCOMMERCE RELEASES AN UPDATE TO THAT TEMPLATE, YOU MUST CHANGE THIS ACCORDINGLY
 
   do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' );
 
   ?>
      <form method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-register register" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag' ); ?> >
 
         <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>
 
         <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>
 
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
               <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
               <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
            </p>
 
         <?php endif; ?>
 
         <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
         </p>
 
         <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>
 
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
               <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
               <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
            </p>
 
         <?php else : ?>
 
            <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
 
         <?php endif; ?>
 
         <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>
 
         <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-register__submit" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Next', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Next', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
         </p>
 
         <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>
 
      </form>
 
   <?php
     
   return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Source: [WooCommerce: Separate Login and Registration Pages](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-separate-login-registration/)

This now redirects me to a 404 of

```
register-now/edit-address/billing/
```

And I need it to redirect me to

```
my-account/edit-address/billing/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace the code from the `woocommerce_registration_redirect` filter hook with:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_registration_redirect( $redirect ) {
    return get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) . 'edit-address/billing';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'filter_woocommerce_registration_redirect', 10, 1 );
```

---

See: [get_permalink( int|WP_Post $post, bool $leavename = false )](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) - Retrieves the full permalink for the current post or post ID